# Printing pdf documnets from windows 8 metro application using C#

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I am currently developing a windows 8 metro application Where I need to print a pdf document on click of print Report button. I used the following code.

```
StorageFolder localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
StorageFile reportFile = await localFolder.GetFileAsync("abc.pdf");
var options = new Windows.System.LauncherOptions();
options.DisplayApplicationPicker = false;
bool success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(reportFile, options);
```

But it will open the pdf document  then the user manually needs to print it.
Is there any way to print the pdf document directly without opening it.?

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Win32 applications which support passing a `verb` like `"print"` to a launched application, there is not currently a standard technique for this in WinRT.

While there might be a PDF viewer that supports a custom query string for `"print"`, the user may have a registered application that doesn't support the syntax another application supports.

The most reliable would be to embed source or a component that could natively print a PDF in WinRT without user interaction.

Comment: I just came to know that it is not possible to show or print the PDF from windows 8 metro app unless we use 3rd party tools. But this can be done in windows 8.1